# Writing for loop output to a text file in python

Tags: python, loops, text-files

I'm new to Python and I'm using it to write FeniCS FEA model fro heat transfer. However, I was able to write code that does what I wanted it to do except to writing thousands of lines that results from a for loop to a text file.

I print that output I want to the screen every time that loop is executed but tried the dozens of answers in this site regarding writing to a text file but all failed. 
here is snippet of the code that contains the for loop

```
for t in numpy.arange(0, t_end, Dt):
    print 'Time ', t, 'Max_temp ', "%.3E " % T.vector().array().max()

    line_n = int(abs(t / line_time))
    hatch = 0.0002

    if (line_n % 2) == 0 
        f.xx = (0.001 + vel*t - (length*line_n - mis))

    else:
        f.xx = (0.019 - vel*t + (length*line_n - mis))
        f.yy = 0.001 + line_n * hatch

    solve(A, T.vector(), b, 'cg')
    print 'Line#', t,
    timestep += 1
    T0.assign(T)
```

now I want to write the output of the two print statements up there to text file instead of writing that to the screen.

P.S. I use a Linux machine

Comment: Open the file and use `file.write()`.

Comment: Please show something that you tried, so we can help you understand what you did wrong instead of just doing it for you.

Comment: Give it write ability when opening too. open(“fileName”, “w”). On another note you may be better writing to a csv rather than a text file based on how your print the data

Answer (score 5):

The quickest route is to use the shell's stdout redirection operator (`>`) to send the output to a file:

```
$ python your_script.py > your_new_file.txt
```

To *append* that file, use the append operator rather than overwriting any file that happens to be there:

```
$ python your_script.py >> your_appended_file.txt
```

If you want a pure Python approach, open the file and write to it with `.write()`:

```
with open('your_new_file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for t in numpy.arange(0, t_end, Dt):
        # attempting to faithfully recreate your print statement
        # but consider using a single format string and .format
        output = ' '.join(('Time ', t, 'Max_temp ', "%.3E " % T.vector().array().max())
        f.write( output )
        ...
```

(And note here the use of `with` to open your file, over manually closing your file with f.close.  The `with` statement makes operations like this much safer and puts less burden on you, the programmer to remember small but important details like remember to close the file.)

Answer (score 3):

I tried below one, i hope this helps, please note that the file will be created in your python folder directory. You can use this as a reference and create for your requirements.

```
f = open('workfile', 'w')
for i in range(3):
    f.write('This is a test\n')
    intvalue =0
    s = str(intvalue)
    f.write(s)

f.close()
```